# Regex match on specific symbol followed by number and letters

Tags: regex

I want to match on a format like the following:

```
1d2h3m4s5z
51d344h33m44s55z
>12d3h
<12m5s
>12h32s
12s4z
12z
```

The following should return false/null:

```
h2m
2g3m4s
455d89m45c
c9m8s
```

so first character has to be `<` or `>` or `''`. Then followed by a format like `1d2h3m4s5z`   but it should return a match if it's just `1d` or `1h` or `>1m3s`.

the idea is that these d h m s z represents `day`, `hour`, `min`, `second`, `z`

This is what I have, `^[><]\d+[dhmsz]\d+[dhmsz]\d+[dhmsz]\d+[dhmsz]\d+[dhmsz]$`  https://regex101.com/r/tO2oF1/6  but it's not fully correct. Only `<2d2h2m2s2z` or `>2d2h2m2s2z`  works.

Comment: Replace the + signs with * or for finer control {,2} will read up to 2 digits.

Comment: And add a + after each [dhmsz] to make it optional.

Comment: [`^([<>]?)(\d+d)?(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?(\d+z)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/tO2oF1/9)

Answer (score 0):

(double)negative-look-behind excludes prefixes: `(?<![^><])`

match the stuff `(\d+[dhmsz]){1,5}`

negative-look-ahead exclude suffix: `(?![^dhmsz])`

all together it's `(?<![^><])(\d+[dhmsz]){1,5}(?![^dhmsz])`

that should match all your cases

Comment: so this 'i1d4m'.match(/[><]?(\d{1,2}[dhmsz])+$/); returns
["1d4m", "4m"] how do i make this return null since it's starting with the letter i

Comment: @PeachIceTea if you can use negative lookbehind it's `(?<![^><])(\d{1,3}[dhmsz])+`

Answer (score 0):

Is 344h a valid input ?

Anyway:

```
^[><]+\d*[dhmsz]+\d*[dhmsz]+\d*[dhmsz]+\d*[dhmsz]+\d*[dhmsz]+$
```

Will work with any length integers. And:

```
\d{,2}
```

For integers  up to 2 digits long.